# Find a rigid motion to transform the curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Say I have a curve $$r(t)=\left(t + \sqrt3\sin t\;,\;\; 2\cos t\;,\;\; \sqrt3t-\sin t\right)$$

I have discovered it is a helix and I want to reparameterize the curve in terms of the standard helix form (r(t)=(acost, asint, bt)).

I need to find a rigid motion to transform the curves, I'm just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: I'm not sure how you discovered it was a helix. But once you know that it has constant curvature and torsion ($\kappa=1/4$, $\tau=-1/4$), the standard formulas for the curvature and torsion of a (circular) helix will tell you what $a$ and $b$ have to be.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
 The equation of the green line is given by: $$l(t)=\left(t ,0, \sqrt3t\right)$$

This is actually an elliptical helix, not a circular helix.

Comment: No, it's a circular helix!!

Comment: Okay, thanks for that.

Comment: I'm as surprised as you are :)